# Firebase causes thread 1: signal SIGBART on Xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Every time I try to add Firebase in the AppDelegate thread 1 error appears. I have tried to do many things but none work. What can I do?

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  BeeCare
//
//  Created by Adrian Castello Ponce on 2/9/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ADCAPO Inc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that has nothing to do with Firebase. Your code works fine for me. I can say "Thread 1: Signal SIGBART" is mostly an error that occurs cause of bad connections from .storyboard to .swift Files. Be sure everything is connected correctly. Sometimes the wrong connections are already marked with yellow ! triangle, especially when the code sited end point from the connection is deleted or out commented. Sometimes you deleted a Label or what ever in storyboard without deleting the connection, sometimes hard to find the connection again without the storyboard item. Try to remember this for the future ;-) 
Hope this helps you...

Comment: when a delete the "firebaseapp.configure()" part of the code all works perfectly